# Is there a rule that creatures without Con scores can not have the Regeneration special ability?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, ability-scores, regeneration

I've heard that there's a rule that creatures without Con scores (e.g. undead) cannot have the regeneration special ability. I can see why that would be the case (immunity to nonlethal damage makes Regeneration pretty powerful), but I'd like to see a rules citation for it if it exists.

Comment: I'm still looking for the actual cite, but I'm pretty sure you hit the nail on the head with the "immunity to non-lethal" part.  Remember that they can regenerate hp, they just have the simpler fast healing instead of "true" regeneration.  Be back with an answer if I can find a 3.5 source...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is right there in [Regeneration ability description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#regeneration):

> [...] A creature must have a Constitution score to have the regeneration ability.

Comment: Well, that's heartbreaking. And makes me look moderately foolish ;)