# Does Regeneration plus Undead Equal Immune to Damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, regeneration

A 1st Level Human takes the Feats Toughness and Troll Blooded:

> Troll Blooded
>
> Type: General
>
> Source: Dragon #319
>
> Your family tree contains the blood of the trolls of the Thillonrian
> Peninsula.
>
> Prerequisite: Toughness
>
> Region: Frost Barbarians, Ice
> Barbarians, Pale, Snow Barbarians, (Oerth).
>
> Benefit: You gain regeneration 1 as an extraordinary ability. Fire and acid deal normal
> damage to you. If you lose a limb or a body part, the lost portion
> regrows in 3d6 days. You can reattach the severed member as a full
> round action by holding it to the stump. You are fatigued while
> exposed to sunlight. Special: You can take this feat at 1st level
> only.

Then they become Undead, via one of the various Templates that grant it.

Regeneration would convert all lethal damage to non-lethal. Undead are immune to non-lethal damage, ergo said character would be immune to all damage other than fire/acid?

EDIT:

Found the same question was already answered [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148348/is-there-a-rule-that-creatures-without-con-scores-can-not-have-the-regeneration).

Comment: Unrelated to your question per se, but likely relevant to your interests: a pugilist fighter with the shake it off special ability (_Dragon_ vol. 310) converts **all** damage into nonlethal, and doesn’t have any rule about needing a Constitution score, so that’s complete damage immunity for one class level and and 1000 XP for necropolitan.

Comment: @KRyan I have a PC with a level in Pugilist and that still didn't occur to me. You're a character building savant. *Hurries off to add this to the stack of random character sheets he'll never use...*

Comment: Re-reading Shake It Off, I can see why I missed this -- it is one of the most weirdly worded abilities I've seen.

Comment: Yeah, it’s bizarre. I seem to recall HeyICanChan preferring to “interpret” it as just incomprehensible and write it off entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this specifically doesn't work. *Monster Manual* 314 describes Regeneration, including the line:

> A creature must have a Constitution score to have the regeneration ability.

That said, there's at least one instance of an undead monster with regeneration: the atropal, a CR 30 undead from the *Epic Level Handbook* (though the ELH is hardly a good example of, well, anything), and there are assorted other ways to become immune to nonlethal damage—*Ilmater's favor*, from *Player's Guide to Faerûn*; Bone Knight, from *Five Nations*—so as a DM, I wouldn't rely on the noninteraction of regeneration and undead to curtail this character concept. Instead, decide if a character being immune to nearly all damage is acceptable for your campaign. In most campaigns, it's too powerful, but in social heavy campaigns, or campaigns with lots of enemies who use save-or-die effects rather than damage, immunity to damage can be in line with other powerful effects (even in a regular campaign, a wizard is more likely to cause problems than an immune-to-damage paladin).

So Troll-Blooded + undeath: no. Troll-Blooded + other ways to become immune to nonlethal: doable, but consider if such a character would be interesting and in line with the other party members. I would err on the side of not making such a character unless you have a veteran DM comfortable challenging such a character in a way that fits with the campaign.

Comment: Ah, yeah, missed that line. Makes sense. And yes, I wouldn't make such a character as a PC without discussing with my DM. As a DM, I might make such an NPC to confront a CoDzillian or some other worthy PC foe.

Answer (score 2):

No. [Per SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#regeneration)

> A creature must have a Constitution score to have the regeneration ability.

And [undead](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#undead) have the following description:

> Traits
>
> An undead creature possesses the following traits (unless otherwise noted in a creature’s entry).
>
> - No Constitution score.

Thus, when character becomes undead, regeneration stops working, creature no longer has this ability, and the two can never synergize.